# How to call a script which is inside the VM from ADF?

Tags: bash, azure-data-factory, virtual-machine

I have a batch script that is inside a VM and I would like to invoke this script using ADF. How can I invoke the script that is inside a VM.

This script will run and download some files on the VM and I have created a pipeline to copy those files from the VM to ADLS.
I was able to figure that the copying part. But how can we call a bash script that resides inside a VM.

Additionally, let me know if we can achieve this with Databricks or Logic Apps or Azure functions or any other method.

Answer (score 0):

> you can use Azure Logic Apps or Azure Functions to invoke the
> script that is inside a VM. You can create a Logic App or Azure
> Function that uses the Azure Automation Hybrid Runbook Worker to
> execute the script on the VM.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail on how to create this in Logic apps or Azure functions. Please do share any links which can be useful. Also this is a batch script. can we invoke this as well?